# iPad Landscape Media Query not working? (WordPress)

Tags: css, wordpress, ipad, media-queries, landscape

This is the same media query I've used for all my other WordPress sites but for some reason it's not working for this particular site.

Often I can get away with just using:

`@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px){}`

But I've tried that, and I've tried:

`@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {}`

But neither are registering. It's not a cache issue, either. 
Additionally, for some reason when I inspect the site, **everything** lists as being received from `site/style.css:1` even though my code is around line `604`.

It was retrieving the css from all of the desktop styling, so as a test I added `@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {}` to my desktop styling, just to cancel it out, and sure enough, now my landscape header is all reverted back default styling (full sized image, default h1 styling, etcetera). Nothing I do triggers the landscape media query, even though the rest are called without any issues at all. I'm about to pull my hair out, and I can't find anything else on Google that quite fits as a solution.

The mobile and iPad Portrait media queries are working perfectly.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: are you using initial scale meta tag?

Comment: Yeppers. It's all there.

Comment: Post a link so we can see what the is?

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment yet:

Do you use any sort of minifying? And are you sure that your .css file has no errors? With both these questions I'm referring to the style.css:1 thingy.

Comment: Not as far as I know. Unfortunately this is a project I'm taking over from a previous designer that I'm just making responsive so there are bound to be things here and there in the code I haven't caught yet.

Comment: Sure there isn't but is there a possibility to look it up myself? So could you provide a link or isn't that meant to be done? ^^